# Excel : is that possible to print one print area from other contained in the same page?

Tags: excel, templates

I drew an excel template contain one print area. The template consists of static information and a table.

I have a java program writes on this template and then prints it to pdf format.

Sometimes, there are lots of information to write ( Table is filled), so I need to set another page to contain the other remaining information.

My idea is to copy this print area and paste it into the same page separated by a page break.

how to restrict printing to first print area if the second remains empty?

Comment: You'll have to set your print area to the `UsedRange` and set a horizontal page break at a certain row if the `UsedRange` exceeds that row.

Comment: can you give more details or a specific help link?